# Swift xcode macos PDFDocument(url: URL) does not create document

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, pdf

I am trying to learn how to display a .pdf file in Swift in an xcode project.  I have code that works if the target file is in the project's bundle, but I cannot display a .pdf that is elsewhere in my user space. In the code that follows (lower half), "pdfURL2" prints out and is the correct URL.  The code prints out "File Exists", so I know that the target file is accessible.  It is a valid .pdf file that I can open with Preview. Using the xcode debugger, "test" is "nil".  Following that, "pdfView.document = test" opens a view, but it is, of course, empty.  If I surround the  "test = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL2)" declaration with a guard" statement, the thread crashes. Hence, I have left that out.

How do I display a .pdf file that is not explicitly in xcode"s project bundle?

```
CODE FOLLOWS:

import Cocoa
import Quartz

class PDFViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fm = FileManager.default


// THIS Code does WORK (for test.pdf in bundle)
        guard let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "pdf")
            else { fatalError("PDF not found") }

        guard let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL)
            else { fatalError("PDF document not created") }
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
// END of code that does WORK (for test.pdf in bundle)


// THis Code does NOT WORK for buildFile.pdf NOT in bundle

        let pdfPath2 = "/Users/myaccount/Desktop/Problematic/buildFile.pdf"
        let pdfURL2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfPath2)
        print("pdfURL2 = \(pdfURL2)")

        if fm.fileExists(atPath: pdfPath2){
            print("File Exists")
            var test = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL2)
            pdfView.document = test
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }  // End ViewDidLoad
} // End PDFViewController
```

Comment: macOS software development 101: Don't hard-code a file path.

Comment: Solution:  I inadvertently had the sandbox turned on and I had an entitlement block. When I turned the sandbox off, the failing code began to work.

Comment: I am currently finding that, building my MacOS document-based app, using XCode 11.5 on a MacOS 10.15.5 system, the call to PDFDocument() raises a link error (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PDFDocument") unless my Deployment Target is set to system 10.15.  This is pretty weird, since in another app built in Objective-C, I can install a PDF file into a PDFView easily with a deployment target of MacOS 10.11.  Wish I knew what was going on, but I don't.  Help!